# I cannot modify hex string for socket communication

Tags: arrays, perl, sockets, hex, byte

I'm a newbie for perl programming.
What I'm trying to do is send some hex string over a socket.
The below is a perl code I'm writing.
It works perfectly.
But I need to modify the hex string from 7th byte to 10th byte which is IP address.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use IO::Socket::INET;
my $data= "\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0a\x14\x1f\x01";
# create a socket
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(
      PeerAddr=>'192.168.1.101',
      PeerPort=>'8121',
      Proto=>'udp) or die $!;
# send some data to server
$sock->send($data);
$sock->close();
exit(0);
```

But I don't know how to modify the IP address section of $data.
If I use like below,

```
my @data= (0x0f,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0a,0x14,0x1f,0x01);
```

I can access the data and modify like below.

```
$data[6] = 0x0a;
$data[7] = 0x14;
$data[8] = 0x1f;
$data[9] = 0x02;
```

But I don't know how to modify $data like this.
Please give me some idea!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $data = join '', map chr, @data;
```

or

```
my $data = pack 'C*', @data;
```

---

Of course, you don't need to convert the whole string into individual numbers.

```
my @ip_octets = ( 10, 20, 31, 1 );
my $data= "\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" . pack('C*', @ip_octets);
```

Better yet, let's start with an actual IP address.

```
use Socket qw( inet_aton );

my $ip_addr = '10.20.31.1';
my $data= "\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" . inet_aton($ip_addr);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a part of a string in perl you can use `substr`as a lvalue like this:

```
substr($data,6,1) = "\x0a";
substr($data,7,1) = "\x14";
substr($data,8,1) = "\x1f";
substr($data,9,1) = "\x02";
```

or

```
substr($data,6,4) = "\x0a\x14\x1f\x01";
```

Comment: I actually added additional question below.